# How to get a String value from one method?

Tags: android, string, function

Hi have a class contains a `method()` and inside the method have a `String` value like this

```
public method() {
        String check = Question.check;
    }
```

Now i need to get this `String` value in a same class as static for futher use  string in a class.

How can i get the string outside the method as `static String`

Please let me know how to get and use it.

Comment: Read the Java before the Android. it is highly recommended

Comment: Make a class with static strings and use setter and getter funtion to retrieve the value when ever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

In your class constructor,get the string value like this,

```
String result=method();
```

after closing the constructor do the following,

```
public String method() {
    String check = Question.check;
     return check;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String method() {
        String check = Question.check;
return check;
    }
```

and you can just call as follows

```
static String returnedData=method();
```